# Как сделать уведомление о новых участниках?

Tags: python, aiogram

Не могу сделать уведомление о новый участниках канала

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def new_chat_member(message: types.Message, chat: -1001920039690):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваше сообщение')
```

Так он не реагирует

Answer (score 0):

Если вы преследуете цель сделать приветственное сообщение в группе, то:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!')
```

Ну а если вы хотите, чтобы бот уведомлял вас в личных сообщениях о новых пользователях в группе, то:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id='ТУТ ID ВАШЕГО ЧАТА С БОТОМ', text='У вас новый пользователь в группе!')
```

Если вы хотите получать уведомления о новых пользователях канала, то, на сколько мне известно (могу ошибаться), такой возможности до сих пор нет. Вы можете только получать список пользователей, которые присоединены к каналу